# Livestreaming webinars from rtmp to DASH

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, mpeg-dash, mp4box, shaka

I need to live-stream RTMP based video to the webpage, and the end result should be dynamic and adaptive (DASH).

Below FFMPEG command works with single stream but it's not adaptive/no low-high selection options.

`ffmpeg -i rtmp://source.mysite.com/live/9 temp/manifest.mpd`

I need something like 1080p RTMP input and 240p, 360p, 480, 720p and 1080p output in single DASH manifest.

Can somebody guide how can I have a stable/tamed, multi-bitrate adaptive result here?